# syntax error : missing ';' before '.'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm unfamiliar with visual C++, so I compiled a simple program using the .NET framework to find my way around it.

```
#pragma once


namespace Netattempt2 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
///
/// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
///          resources associated with this form.
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtbxUsername;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnClick;
protected: 

protected: 

private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->txtbxUsername = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->btnClick = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // txtbxUsername
        // 
        this->txtbxUsername->Location = System::Drawing::Point(94, 17);
        this->txtbxUsername->Name = L"txtbxUsername";
        this->txtbxUsername->Size = System::Drawing::Size(174, 20);
        this->txtbxUsername->TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // btnClick
        // 
        this->btnClick->Location = System::Drawing::Point(204, 43);
        this->btnClick->Name = L"btnClick";
        this->btnClick->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 23);
        this->btnClick->TabIndex = 1;
        this->btnClick->Text = L"Click Me!";
        this->btnClick->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->btnClick->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 20);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(76, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 2;
        this->label1->Text = L"Enter name -->";
        this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::label1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 73);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->btnClick);
        this->Controls->Add(this->txtbxUsername);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Hello World!";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void btnClick_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             MessageBox.Show("Welcome to windows " + txtbxUsername.Text, "Hi there...");
         }
};
}
```

And this line:

```
MessageBox.Show("Welcome to windows " + txtbxUsername.Text, "Hi there...");
```

Returns this error:

```
Form1.h(114) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
```

Taking out the line allows the program to compile, but the message box is more or less necessary to the program.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: Note that this is not C++:  it is C++/CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```
MessageBox::Show("Welcome to windows " + txtbxUsername->Text, "Hi there..."); 
          ^^                                          ^^
```

Comment: `txtbxUsername.Text` also needs to be `txtbxUsername->Text`, I think.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, yes thanks my eyes are a little tired and stopped to the first. Time to go to bed I think.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed everything. I'll have to find out some of the differences between C++ and C# syntax as I figure this out, I suppose.